# A simple SUM on all records of a column doesn't work in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I am trying to find total revenue earned by cabbies from this [data set](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-public-data:new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018) on google big query [here](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/results/prefab-envoy-260900:US.bquijob_3adaff5b_16ec9d1cee3) but sum(total_amount) doesn't seem to work. It says

> Error: Field total_amount is of type STRING which is not supported for
>   SUM

even though it is defined as numeric data type by default. I did some casting things but then the sum says 0.

I don't seem to find why.

Things I tried:

1. Specifying the column as `INTEGER` in SUM like `SUM(INTEGER(total_amount))` returned 0.
2. CASTED the column name to `INTEGER` using CAST type returned 0.
3. Checked if there are any NULL columns but there is none.

Here is my query:

```
Select sum(total_amount) from
[bigquery-public-data:new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NUMERIC data type in Legacy SQL has limited support

So, instead try running your query in BigQuery Standard SQL as in below example

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT SUM(total_amount) 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018`
```

with result

```
Row f0_  
1   1837861124.95
```